# How to factor out Django model fields into their own model, keeping data?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a Django ORM Model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)

    bar_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    bar_data = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to factor out `bar_id` and `bar_data` into a separate model class:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    bar = models.ForeignKey('Bar', null=True, blank=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I already know for sure that each `bar_id` has only a single value for `bar_data` associated with it, and `bar_data` is always `None` if `bar_id` is `None`, so it should be possible to migrate the old `bar_data` field into the new `Bar` objects, I just don't know how to do it.

Hoe can I migrate to these new models while keeping data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper, django-ish way to do this is to:

- Create a schema migration (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/) with the new model (`Bar`) - this migrations should just add the `Bar` without any instances
- Create a data migration (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that will copy the data from the old model to the new one. You just need to loop all `Foo` instances and create `Bar` instances based on your requirements. You can also try to create a backwards data migration (i.e loop all `Bar` instances and update `Foo` instances properly) for this data migration if you really need it. Keep in mind that while this migration is running you will have both `Foo` and `Bar` and the `bar_id` and `bar_data` fields in `Foo`.
- Create a second schema migration that will delete (remove) the non-needed fields (`bar_id` and `bar_data`) from `Foo`.

As I said, this is the proper, django-ish way to do it. However, if you want something quick and dirty, you can check out my article for doing such changes in your database using only postgresql (with PL/pgsql): https://spapas.github.io/2017/07/04/postgresql-auto-create-category-column/